# Less records are found in apache-drill when using it with HBase

Tags: hbase, apache-drill

I am new to `apache-drill`. I am using it with `HBase`. I provided proper configuation and enables storage for HBase using its UI at `localhost:8047`:

```
{
  "type": "hbase",
  "config": {
    "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "localhost",
    "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort": "2181"
  },
  "size.calculator.enabled": false,
  "enabled": true
}
```

I have a table in Hbase with `120000` records in it.

While finding it in `apache-drill` using:

```
select * from hbase.`table`;
```

I got `2,731` records. Is there any constraint on  the number of rows in output data in `apache-drill`?

Comment: May be you have 120k columns and 2731 rows ? Can't say much without your data structure.

Comment: @halil `I  have a table in Hbase with 120000 records in it. `.. not columns.. My schema is simple with 4 columns..

Comment: How did you verify that you indeed have 120K rows in HBase?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov using HBase shell (natively)..

Comment: Cool, just wanted to eliminate the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

A similar bug was reported [DRILL-4271](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4271). It looks like after some investigation the issue was due to a bug in HBase for versions before 1.0.1 and 1.1.0. Currently Drill 1.12 has support up to HBase version 1.1.3 . I would recommend trying again with Drill 1.12 and HBase version 1.1.0 - 1.1.3.